# JQUERY getJSON / ajax response not being processed

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I am sending a json request to a server as below:

```
$.getJSON("prod_search.php?type=getCustInfo&custID="+custID, function(json) {
  alert(json.address);
  $("#invAddress").html(json.address);
  $("#currency").html(json.second);
});
```

Using firebug to check, the response is below, but the alert shows 'undefined' and no values are inserted.

```
[{"address":"abc123","second":"ABC"}]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are the [] brackets added for readability or anything? because it looks like its an array with an object in it, does alert(json[0].address) work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
json=json[0]
```

at first in the callback.
You receive an array, and the object you like to access is the first(and only) item inside this array.

Comment: or return `{"address":"abc123","second":"ABC"}`

Comment: Guys, you are both legends. I spent all day yesterday staring at this!

Comment: i agree with this answer. [] <-- array {} <-- object so a [{}] would return an array with an object